# Two way binding not working with a variable in a Modal (Subcontroller) with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hello I got a list of products and I want people to select one of them and then a modal displays where they can enter extra info (a comment). I am using 'AngularJS' with 'Angular-UI' and 'Angular-UI-bootstrap'. I thought I would be able how to get it working with the example given at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal However I can t seem to save the Comment. It always stays "Please enter a comment". Here is the code:

The modal template:

```
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="orderModal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="alignleft">{{Product.Naam}}</div>
            <div class="alignright">€{{Product.Prijs}}</div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            <p>Heeft u een nog opmerking bij dit product?</p>
            <input type="text" name="Comment" ng-model="Comment" />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">Toevoegen</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Annuleren</button>
        </div>
    </script>
```

Here is are the controllers:

```
productModule.controller("ProductsController", function ($scope, bootstrappedData, $modal, $log) {
    $scope.products = bootstrappedData.products;

    ...
    $scope.AddNormalOrder = function (product) {
            ....
    };

    $scope.OpenModal = function (product)
    {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'orderModal',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: {
                product: function () {
                    return product;
                }
            }
         });
        modalInstance.result.then(function (order) {
            $scope.AddNormalOrder(order);
        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };
});
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, product) {
    $scope.Product = product;
    $scope.Comment = "Please enter a comment"; // it never changes
    $scope.ok = function () {
        var order = $scope.Product;
        order.Comment = $scope.Comment; // Here even if I check the value in debug after                     //changing it it still stays the same value ("Please enter a comment")
        $modalInstance.close(order);
    };
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
};
```

TL;DR
The $scope.Comment in the ModalInstanceCtrl never changes if change the value in .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a scoping issue. 
Try this:

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, product, $log) {
    $scope.Product = product;
    $scope.Product.Comment = "Please enter a comment";
    $scope.ok = function () {
        var order = $scope.Product;
        $log.info(order.Comment);  //You should see the updated Comment in your console
        $modalInstance.close(order);
    };
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
};
```

Change your input to this:

```
<input type="text" name="Comment" ng-model="Product.Comment" />
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Your solution works, but could you explain why? Or better, why is the upper example not working?

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is an issue with the bootstrap modal code.

See this for a different fix
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23518971/433390

which is, use $parent.Comment in the template with the code that was posted in the question

```
<input type="text" name="Comment" ng-model="$parent.Comment" />
```

this for an explanation
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/969