# Angular UI Modal 2 Way Binding Not Working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am adding an Angular UI Modal where I am passing the scope through to the Modal Window for 2 way binding. I used the `resolve` method to pass the scope value. Doing so works sort of works meaning when the ng-model value changes in parent, it reflects inside the modal window. However, if the value changes inside the modal window, it is not reflecting in the parent ng-model. Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ParentController">
        <br />
        <input type="text" ng-model="textbox.sample" /> 
        <a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open(textbox.sample)">Click Me</a> 

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="ModalContent.html">
            <input type = "text" ng-model= "ngModel" / >
        </script>


        <br />{{ textbox }}        
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('ParentController', function ($scope, $modal) {

    $scope.textbox = {};

    // MODAL WINDOW
    $scope.open = function (_ngModel) { // The ngModel is passed from open() function in template   
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'ModalContent.html',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl, 
            resolve: {
                ngModel: function () {
                    return _ngModel;
                }
            } // end resolve
        });
    };
});

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, ngModel) {
    $scope.ngModel = ngModel;

};
```

**Why isint the 2 way binding between parent and modal instance not working in the above code?**

Comment: Where are you actually expecting to see the two-way binding happen, where you're printing out `{{textbox}}` ?  If that's the case, you're no longer acting on `$scope.textbox` once you're in the modal, you're creating a copy of `$scope.textbox` when you pass it as `_ngModel` and then you modal `$scope` item is `$scope.ngModel`... Try printing `{{ngModel}}` on the parent and see what happens

Comment: Its better to pass $scope as option parameter in modals open function

Comment: @Tom When I said 2 way binding, what I meant by that is I want the text box input in parent and modal window to change if any of those values changes. For instance, in my example, the ng-model for `input` in parent and the `input` in modal window is the same. So when I type something in parent `input` and then open the modal, I can see the modal `input` having the same value. But when I type something inside the modal instance's `input`, it is not updating it on parent input. When those 2 are binded by the same ng-model, shouldnt it update?

Comment: @blackops_programmer, they aren't the same `ng-model="ngModel"` and `ng-model="textbox.sample"` are different and thus will not update eachother.  The reason it works from the parent to the modal is because you're setting that every time you open the modal window.

Comment: aha.. so if I want the parent ng-model to reflect any change done inside the modal instance, how do I do that? Would placing a `$watch` in parent controller work in this case? If so, how can I add that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're under the impression that `ng-model="textbox.sample"` in the parent and `ng-model="ngModel"` in the modal are the same because you are passing `textbox.sample` to the modal and you're able to see the correct value in the modal window.  The only reason this is working is because you're explicitly setting the `$scope.ngModel` property every time to modal window opens.

One way to make this work how you expect is to just use the `$scope.textbox.sample` property in both places, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Perhaps the proper way would be to use the `modalInstance.result` promise, something like this:

Create a button on the modal and make it's `ng-click="ok()"`

```
$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.ngModal); // will return this to the modalInstance.result
}
```

And then in the parent controller, or whatever opens the modal window:

```
$scope.open = function (_ngModel) { // The ngModel is passed from open() function in template   
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'ModalContent.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl, 
        resolve: {
            ngModel: function () {
                return _ngModel;
            }
        } // end resolve
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
        $scope.textbox.sample = result;
    });
};
```

Comment: You are very right. I have totally misunderstood since I thought passing the ng-model through open() will give the same ng-model scope to the modal and automatically bind both models. Your answers clears that for me. I love your suggestion of using the `modalInstance.result` promise to update the parent's ng-model and sync it with the modal instance. Makes total sense! I will give that a try on my code and will report back.

Comment: Sorry I'm back again. In my code I am now passing on the updated ng-model via `$modalInstance.close`. However, I am having a bit of trouble adding the last code in parent controller that process the promise. When I added that code, I am getting `modalInstance is not defined` error. I think I am placing this code in a wrong location inside my parent controller. Does this go inside the  `$scope.open` function or outside? Do I need to add `$modalInstance` DI in parent controller also? Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need need to do the `modalInstance.result` in the same block that you define `modalInstance`, i.e., `var modalInstance = $modal.open({...});  modalInstance.result.then(...)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helps, and I like idea to use result promise.

Comment: Can we get a Plunker for this.

Answer (score 10):

Change:

```
<input type = "text" ng-model= "ngModel" / >
```

Into:

```
<input type = "text" ng-model= "$parent.ngModel" / >
```

This has to do with transclusion. Check: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/969

Answer (score 2):

For me none of the above worked.

Instead I had to do like was suggested in [this comment in github](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2110#issuecomment-41838970).

The variable to be binded to must be an object, not only a simple value.

For example, if `$scope.value` does not work, it will work if you use `$scope.someObject.value`.