# Unintented two-way data binding in angular bootstrap UI modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In implementing Bootstrap UI modal for Angular, it looks like it's two-way data binding between the controller and modal instance. I thought the modal would be isolated. What I am doing wrong? Changes a user makes to data should be applied only when the user closes the modal.

**Controller**

```
$scope.selectedTopic = {
    topicId : 'ABC',
    tags    : [1,3]
  }

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var topicData = { id: $scope.selectedTopic.topicId, tags: $scope.selectedTopic.tags };
    var aTags = {
        tags: [
            {name:'foo', id: 1},
            {name:'bar', id: 2},
            {name:'robo', id: 3},
            {name:'lino', id: 4},
          ]
      }

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        activeTopic: function() {
          return topicData;
        },
        availableTags: function() {
           return aTags;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (activeTopic) {
      $scope.selectedTopic.tags = activeTopic.tags;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
```

**Modal Instance Controller**

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl',
      function ($scope, $modalInstance,  availableTags, activeTopic) {

   $scope.availableTags    = availableTags;
   $scope.activeTopic      = {
      id: activeTopic.id,
      tags: activeTopic.tags
   };


  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.activeTopic);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

[See Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FMMCMNIFYYLzln6W4Xai?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should probably create a deep copy of the object you are resolving to the modal

```
activeTopic: function() {
      return angular.copy(topicData);
},
```

[Angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

[Forked Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/okkP7EGTZQiFhiTsA3Kl?p=preview)

Comment: This answer looks correct but I'm curious as to why the modal isn't an isolated scope. This questioner also had a similar, albeit opposite issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23518835/angular-ui-modal-2-way-binding-not-working

Comment: so topicData is being passed to the modal by reference. So when using the angular.copy its passing a copy of the object instead of a reference to the existing one.

Comment: This answer is perfect. Sometimes I noticed returning the ngmodel object directly to modal causes some unwanted two way binding even when modal is dismissed. So `angular.copy` is a very good solution. Thanks.